# Remove an XML node using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm trying to remove `<Element>SlowPollGroup</Element>` from the XML below. `<Markers>` is four levels deep in the XML file. I've already found `<Markers>` as $markersExists using `$markersExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode("./Markers")` script.

```
  <Markers>
    <Element>Group2</Element>
    <Element>Group3</Element>
    <Element>Group4</Element>
    <Element>HWSimSubscription</Element>
    <Element>DIO_TC</Element>
    <Element>CmdSubGroup</Element>
    <Element>FastPollGroup</Element>
    <Element>SlowPollGroup</Element>
    <Element>HWSimPoll</Element>
    <Element>WriteOnly</Element>
  </Markers>
```

I've tried the script below:

```
        $groupNameSPG = "SlowPollGroup"
        $delMarkerElem = $groupNameSPG

        LogWrite ("Searching for Markers")
        $markersExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode("./Markers")
        if ($null -ne $markersExists) {
            LogWrite ("Markers found")

            foreach($element in $markersExists.Element) {
                if ( $element -eq $delMarkerElem) {
                    LogWrite ($delMarkerElem + " found")
                    $delElem = $element.ParentNode
                    $delMarkerElemFound = $true
                    break
                }
                LogWrite ("Searching for [$delMarkerElem] again")
            }

            if ($delMarkerElemFound) {
                $markersExists.RemoveChild($element) | Out-Null
                LogWrite ("Removed => [$delMarkerElem]")
            }
            else {
                LogWrite ("delMarkerElemFound => [$delMarkerElemFound]")
            }
        }
```

Log file excerpt looks like below:

```
Searching for Markers
Markers found
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
Searching for [SlowPollGroup] again
SlowPollGroup found
Removed => [SlowPollGroup]
```

However, when I tested the whole script in Windows PowerShell ISE on Win10, the output looks like below:

[PowerShell Error v01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO4QM.png)

I've used the code below:

```
        $groupsExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode("./Groups")
        if ($null -ne $groupsExists) {
            LogWrite ("Groups found")
            foreach($element in $groupsExists.Element) {
                if ( $element.Name -eq $groupElemName) {
                    LogWrite ($groupElemName + " found")
                    $groupElemNameFound = $true
                    break
                }
                LogWrite ("Searching for " + $groupElemName + " again")
            }

            if ($groupElemNameFound) {
                $groupsExists.RemoveChild($element) | Out-Null
                LogWrite ("Removed => $groupElemName")
            }
        }
```

on the XML below

```
  <Groups>
    <Element>
      <Name>Group1</Name>
      <PollInterval>200</PollInterval>
      <UseDataSubscription>True</UseDataSubscription>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <Name>AlarmGroup</Name>
      <PollInterval>1000</PollInterval>
    </Element>
    <Element>
      <Name>GVL_TC</Name>
      <PollInterval>100</PollInterval>
    </Element>
  </Groups>
```

to remove the last Element, i.e.

```
    <Element>
      <Name>GVL_TC</Name>
      <PollInterval>100</PollInterval>
    </Element>
```

and it worked. I understand both XML structures are different and I suspect $element in the top script contains only 'SlowPollGroup', not `<Element>SlowPollGroup</Element>`. I've been at this over the weekend trying out various scripts offered from Google searches, but no dice. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this script works as I want it to:

```
        LogWrite ("Searching for Markers")
        $markersExists = $vendor.SelectSingleNode("./Markers")
        if ($null -ne $markersExists) {
            LogWrite ("Markers found")

            # $delMarkerElem needs to be within ''
            $node = $markersExists.SelectSingleNode("./Element[.='$delMarkerElem']")

            if ($null -ne $node) {
                $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
                LogWrite ("Removed => Element node=[$node] with delMarkerElem=[$delMarkerElem]")
            }
            else {
                LogWrite ("Not found - Element node=[$node] with delMarkerElem=[$delMarkerElem]")
            }
        }
```

Modified from this script:

```
$node = $conns.SelectSingleNode("//Description[.='HP Command View EVA']")
while ($node -ne $null) {
    $node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
    $node = $conns.SelectSingleNode("//Description[.='HP Command View EVA']")
}
```

found from http://jon.netdork.net/2013/01/09/removing-xml-elements-using-powershell/